# What permissions need to be included for AWS step function role to enable X-ray?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, state-machine, aws-step-functions, x-ray

I'm currently looking at some resource on how to enable X-ray for my stepfunction statemachine, from this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-xray-tracing.html#xray-concept-create

"When you enable X-Ray for an existing state machine, you must ensure that you have an IAM policy that grants sufficient permissions for X-Ray to perform traces. You can either add one manually, or generate one. For more information, see the IAM policy section for X-Ray."

There are so many permissions for X-ray, I wonder which ones I need? I'd like to add them to my step function role manually, but I don't want to add all of them including the unneeded ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following links will guide you based on your use-case:

1. [Basic IAM permissions policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/xray-iam.html), I would suggest to start with this. Then reduce/add based on your use-cases.
2. [How AWS X-Ray works with IAM](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/xray/latest/devguide/security_iam_service-with-iam.html#security_iam_service-with-iam-id-based-policies), a bit in details.

Furthermore, you can use [AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) to make things easy. Here, AWS X-Ray actions are listed under Type of Policy as IAM Policy